# Minimum cost to set internet in all rooms?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, minimum, undirected-graph

There are n rooms in a hostel. We want to supply internet to all the rooms, laying a proper network.

For each room 'i', we can either have a router directly with the cost 'router[i]', or connect that room through an ethernet cable pulled from another neighbor room’s router. The cost to lay ethernet cable between the two rooms is given by ethernet array, containing '(i, j, c)' which means it costs 'c' to lay ethernet cable between room 'i' and 'j' (or) 'j' to 'i'.

- Connection is undirected, and we can have multiple ways to set the
  network up
- At least 1 person has to take an initial router connection if everyone else intends to pull an ethernet cable from him.
- If 1 person has pulled an ethernet from their neighbour, another neighbour of them also can pull ethernet from them. There's no limit/constraint on this chain.

Example:

```
minCostConnecting(n, router, ethernet)


n = 5
router = [1,2,1,5,3]
ethernet = [[2,4,1], [0,2,3], [1,3,3], [0,4,1]]
```

Output = 8

At Room 0 and Room 2, set up a router. Cost = router[0] + router[2] = 2
Connect rooms 0 and 4 at a cost of 1.
At room 1 set up a router, with cost 2.
From room 1 to 3, setup an ethernet cable at cost 3.

I am unsure of the best approach for solving this problem. I believe we need to at least lay internet in 1 room, and thought greedily choosing the cheapest room to lay the connection would work best? But then I am unsure how to connect the rooms properly given that we can also chain connections together?

Any sense of the algorithms/approaches here would be appreciated

Comment: What kind of approach are you looking for? The most asymptotically-efficient algorithm in theory? Or just a python code that works on this small example? Your small example has only 5 vertices and 4 edges, and each room can have a router or not, and each edge can have an ethernet cable or not, so the total number of combinations is only `2**(4+5) = 512`. Just bruteforce-iterate through all combinations, filter out the ones in which a room doesn't have internet, compute the cost of the combinations that remain, and return the solution with minimum cost.

Comment: the `ethernet` does not contains all possible connections. Is the possible connections limited? In your example there is no value for ethernet cable between rooms 1 and 2 for instance.

Comment: Even if you intend to implement a smarter algorithm later, I recommend writing the bruteforce algorithm first. It's simple, and if you implement a more complicated algorithm later, you can compare its results with those of the bruteforce algorithm to test that it works.

Comment: [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527), I take it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds exactly like MST problem. (Minimum Spanning Tree, for more info check the wiki -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)

Firstly I would make a directed weighted graph of the internet cost which the nodes are the rooms and the edges weight are the cost of the laying the ethernet between the two rooms.

beside the rooms nodes I would add another node for the initial router with edges weight corresponding to the cost of the router in each room. this node guarantees that atleast one person has to take a router but also more than one person can buy another router (if it's cost effective).

Now all is left is to find the MSP (takes O(m + n log n) using Prim's algorithm) and that's it

Comment: @AbhinavMathur That extra node represents "the Internet" (the rest of it, strictly speaking). The MST has one or more connections from it. If there is more than one, then it was cost effective.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat missed that detail, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import heapq

def minCostConnecting(n, router, ethernet):
    # Create a graph with n vertices
    graph = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    
    # Add edges to the graph with the costs
    for i, j, c in ethernet:
        graph[i].append((j, c))
        graph[j].append((i, c))
    
    # Initialize the heap with the costs of the routers
    heap = [(cost, i) for i, cost in enumerate(router)]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    
    # Initialize the set of visited vertices
    visited = set()
    
    # Initialize the total cost
    total_cost = 0
    
    # Loop until all vertices are visited
    while len(visited) < n:
        # Pop the cheapest router from the heap
        cost, u = heapq.heappop(heap)
        
        # If the router's vertex hasn't been visited yet, add it to the visited set and update the total cost
        if u not in visited:
            visited.add(u)
            total_cost += cost
        
        # Visit all the neighbors of the router's vertex and add them to the heap if they haven't been visited yet
        for v, c in graph[u]:
            if v not in visited:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (c, v))
    
    return total_cost

n = 5
router = [1,2,1,5,3]
ethernet = [[2,4,1], [0,2,3], [1,3,3], [0,4,1]]
print(minCostConnecting(n, router, ethernet)) # Output: 8
```